# Netkit connectivity issue between two networks with a specific host

Tags: ping

I am trying to create 2 networks using 2 routers in between, i have 10 hosts, and 9 of them ping successfully, and 1 is not pinging (and i am configuring exactly the same way as the others). Here is the code to see if someone can tell me whats the problem.

lab.conf

```
C1[1]="A"
C2[1]="A"

R1[1]="A"

R2[1]="A"

LB1[0]="A"
LB1[1]="B"

LB2[0]="A"
LB2[1]="B"

S11[0]="B"
S12[0]="B"
S21[0]="B"
S22[0]="B"
```

C1.startup

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.10 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.2.11
```

C2.startup

```
ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.13 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.2.14
```

R1.startup

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.9 netmask 255.255.255.248 broadcast 192.168.2.15 up
```

R2.startup

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.2.12 netmask 255.255.255.248 broadcast 192.168.2.15 up
```

LB1.startup

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.11 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.11 netmask 255.255.255.248 up

iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --destination 192.168.2.11 --match statistic --mode nth --every 2 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.10
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --destination 192.168.2.11 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.9
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source 192.168.2.8/29 --destination 192.168.1.8/29 --jump MASQUERADE

echo "watch 'iptables -t nat -vnL'" >> /root/.bashrc
```

LB2.startup

```
/sbin/ifconfig eth0 192.168.2.14 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
/sbin/ifconfig eth1 192.168.1.14 netmask 255.255.255.248 up

iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --destination 192.168.2.14 --match statistic --mode nth --every 2 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.12
iptables --table nat --append PREROUTING --destination 192.168.2.14 --jump DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.13
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --source 192.168.2.8/29 --destination 192.168.1.8/29 --jump MASQUERADE

echo "watch 'iptables -t nat -vnL'" >> /root/.bashrc
```

S11.startup

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.10 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.11
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

S12.startup

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.9 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.11
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

S21.startup

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.12 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.14
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

S22.startup

```
ifconfig eth0 192.168.1.13 netmask 255.255.255.248 up
route add default gw 192.168.1.14
/etc/init.d/apache2 start
```

My problematic host is S22.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the lab.conf at the end did not had an enter or two, idk exactly, because i just insert it twice, and it started recognizing the S22!!